# Move saved games from Wii to PC

Tags: pc, nintendo-wii, lego-star-wars

My younger son (3) broke the disc for our Wii version of Lego Star Wars, The Complete Saga. My older son (7) would like to play it some more, and I'm thinking of just buying it for the PC through Steam (and leave the Wii for Mario games, I guess). The hitch is that, together, we had worked on a saved game that's about 99% done. (We only need to finish collecting the blue cannisters.) Would there be any way to move the saved games from the Wii to the PC in this situation? Like, can I move them to a SD card and put them on the PC? Would they even work, even if I could physically do it? If not, I may just capitulate and buy it again for the Wii.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that the saved games were compatible across platforms, but I'm willing to be proved wrong.

Comment: If you're buying a new copy anyway, why not pick up one for the Wii and not worry about cross-platform issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no way to use it on the PC game. This is because the difference in formats. I believe your best best is to buy a new copy for Wii.

Addendum: http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wii/en_na/data.jsp#SDcopy

For backing up purposes.

Comment: How do you know for sure?

Comment: I copied the save game files from the Wii to an SD card. It's a single .bin file. As far as I can tell from Googling, the PC saved games are two .bin files. Also, it seems the Wii version has all 4 (6?) save slots in that single file, whereas the PC version stores them in separate folders.